# tooltip is not visible on hover effect on <a>

Tags: html, css

i am having a problem with the  on :hover the tooltip is supposed to visible, but it does not happening .I am using only CSS no js included.Need help.
Thank you in advance...:)
here is my css :

```
.tooltip{
        position: relative;
        opacity: 0;
        padding: 10px;
        background: #9B59B6;
        border-radius: 5px;

    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease-in;
      -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-in;
            transition:all 0.2s ease-in;
     }
```

HTML :

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="tooltip">Hello ! This is tooltip....</span>
  <a href="#" class="show">Hover Me !</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are you setting it to be visible?

Comment: Could you provide us with a jsfiddle so we can see what's happening? That would help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need some code to actually trigger the animation.

In my example below, I have nested the `<span>` inside the `<a>` in order to use `:hover`.

```
<div class="wrapper">  
  <a href="#" class="show">
     Hover Me !
     <span class="tooltip">Hello ! This is tooltip....</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

```
a:hover span {
    opacity:1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6RV5n/

### EDIT:

Here's the same concept but using a CSS adjacent sibling selector so as not to nest the elements:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <a href="#" class="show">Hover Me !</a>
 <span class="tooltip">Hello ! This is tooltip....</span>
</div>
```

```
a.show:hover + span.tooltip {
    opacity:1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7pT8Y/3/

Keep in mind that CSS sibling selectors [may not work](http://caniuse.com/css-sel2) in older version of IE.

Comment: Great! Also see @sriraman's answer.. there are various ways to perform the CSS selection depending on how you want/need to structure the HTML.

Comment: i could not understand that why you have used ".tooltip" inside ".show" ? Can we use it outside the ".show" and how it will be visible through the :hover on".show" ?

Comment: I only nested `.tooltip` to avoid CSS sibling selectors for maximum [browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/css-sel2). But you can keep the elements as siblings and use a sibling selector or put the `:hover` action on the `.wrapper` like in @sriraman's answer. The basic concept is the same: set `opacity:1` somehow/somewhere.

Comment: Added sibling selector method to my answer.

Comment: which one is better method while working on project and to reduce Browser compatibility ?

Comment: If js can be useful than how it should be ? i don't have any idea about it.please suggest using js.

Comment: Either method is fine. Internet Explorer doesn't support sibling selectors prior to version 7. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

Comment: Regarding a JS solution: that sounds like a different question since you specifically asked for CSS/HTML. In my opinion, JS would be more cumbersome and unnecessary in this context, but you can try experimenting with it.

Comment: Finally with the help of you guys @showdev and sriraman the result is quite nice check it here : http://jsfiddle.net/thekiddev/sYS4a/

Answer (score 3):

If you need to display the tooltip while the user hovering on the div wrapper..
Use the following CSS.

```
.wrapper:hover > .tooltip{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Check this...  http://jsfiddle.net/TsQB5/

[EDITED]

```
.tooltip{
     display:none;
 }

 .show:hover > .tooltip{
     display: block;
 }
```

This can solve the problem..

Comment: I've checked that but it will be displayed  on hovering the wrapper my question was to display the tooltip on hovering ".show" but now it is solved right here check it .. http://jsfiddle.net/thekiddev/sYS4a/

Comment: But, still the tooltip is displaying just by hovering on the space allocated for the tooltip ( near hover me button. because tooltip also available inside the .show class only  ).

If you add `display:none` to the tooltip, then you can avoid this problem.